# Phone/Text/Contact History?

Tags: logging, call-history

Does Android keep a log of numbers contacted similar to the Phone Call Log/History but for texts?

My mother accidentally deleted a bunch of texts. The actually messages themselves are unimportant, but now she has completely lost the contact number and I am wondering if their is a way of pulling up the number of the last text(s) sent.

Answer (score 1):

No. It doesn't. They are [not backed up like apps,settings and call history](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6305834?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en). Only on Pixel phones SMSes are backed up.

There is a possibility though - If she had called that person and if backup was enabled on the phone and if she remembers the date and time when she spoke (lot of IFs) then you could take a backup of all important stuff on the phone do a factory reset, restore from Google backup and reconstruct from call history, to get the contact number . It's a slim chance  with so many IFs.

You need to weigh the efforts of backing up data and restoring the phone subject to her remembering when she called and of course backup being enabled on device